# How do I dynamically change a parameter in a Python API call

Tags: json, python-3.x, vimeo-api

I am trying to dynamically change the page parameter in an API call in Python so I can access all of the JSON data for my files on Vimeo.  What I don't understand is how to change a parameter dynamically instead of hardcoding the number. As you can see in the code below, the 'page' is 3 but I don't understand how to insert a parameter so I can iterate through the pages and get the JSON data for each page.  Thank you for your help.

```
uri = 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos'
# Asking the JSON to only get the two fields we are interested in
response = v.get(uri, params={'fields': 'name, uri', 'page': 3, 'per_page': 100})
```

Here is part of the API return.

```
{
  'total': 3278,
  'page': 1,
  'per_page': 100,
  'paging': {
    'next': '/me/videos?fields=name%2C%20uri&per_page=100&page=2',
    'previous': None,
    'first': '/me/videos?fields=name%2C%20uri&per_page=100&page=1',
    'last': '/me/videos?fields=name%2C%20uri&per_page=100&page=33'
  },
  'data': [
    {
      'uri': '/videos/356967749',
      'name': 'Connecting Smallholder Farmers to Science'
    },
    {
      'uri': '/videos/356880620',
      'name': 'pro_test_upload'
    },
    {
      'uri': '/videos/356880402',
      'name': 'Amazing Apollo Stories with Charles Fishman'
    },
    {
      'uri': '/videos/356728892',
      'name': 'tot_190829'
    },
    {
      'uri': '/videos/356481229',
      'name': 'com_acw_johnson.mov'
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the total number of results using the first page, then paginate using that value:

```
import math
uri = 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos'
first_page = requests.get(
    uri, 
    params={
        'fields': 'name, uri', 
        'page': 1, 
        'per_page': 100}).json()
total_pages = math.ceil(first_page["total"] / first_page["per_page"])
for page in total_pages:
    response = requests.get(
        uri, 
        params={
            'fields': 'name, uri', 
            'page': page, 
            'per_page': 100})
    # do things
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I will give this a try.  I appreciate it.

Comment: One more question on this.  If my line of code goes over 79 characters and it involves something like the line below, what is the best way to separate those lines since?  I have googled this but not found anything consistent.  Thank you.

`first_page = requests.get(uri, params={'fields': 'name, uri', 'page': 1, 'per_page': 100}).json()`

Comment: @user3324136 It's a matter of personal preference and there is no "best way", but the recommended methods can be found in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I updated my answer to demonstrate how _I_ usually format it. Note that 80 characters is not a hard rule either; it is a PEP-8 recommendation itself.